# Fastest .NET way to retrieve the most metadata from files in a remote network share?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, io, .net, fileinfo

Of the available .NET `System.IO` methods/classes, what is the most efficient way to retrieve an entire directory listing on a remote network share (assume a slow, non-LAN speed link)?

For 10,000+ files, need to grab:

1. Name
2. Size
3. Date Last Modified
4. Date Created

There appears to be a huge performance difference in the amount of time it takes to loop through `FileInfo` objects for this information vs. the amount of time that Windows Explorer can display the same thing.

Comment: What kinds of time differences?  Are we talking about minutes or seconds?

Comment: Minutes... maybe 10 mins for a large folder vs. 30 secs for Windows Explorer

Comment: That big of a difference indicates there is a flaw in your approach.  Can you post your approach?  I wouldn't be shocked if Windows keeps a cache of the folder, I know when my network drives are lost, they can appear to be offline even when they are online.

Comment: I figured FileInfo would have to be going back to each individual file to get the Date Last Modified or something, app seems to bog down on retrieving the time. Confirming this...

Comment: If you look at the implementation of the `FileInfo` class (and the base `FileSystemInfo`), you would find that a lot of the info is lazily loaded individually.  In particular, the timestamps.  It might be better to just use the winapi and get all the info directly all at once somehow or other method.  Maybe even create a tool on that share that gets the requested info and get the results in a single request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is a side-effect of a design choice made in .NET 1.0 for the FileInfo class.  It doesn't store the property values when the FileInfo object is constructed, it is retrieved from the file when you use the property getter.  That way you always get the up-to-date value of the property.  Which of course matters a great deal for the size and date properties, they mutate easily.  The round-trip through the network however makes it slow.

It was solved in .NET 4 with the added DirectoryInfo.EnumerateXxxx() methods.  The emphasis on an enumerator made it now obvious that you got a potentially stale copy of the file info.  But avoiding the round-trip.

Solves your problem if you can use .NET 4.  You'll need to pinvoke FindFirstFile, FindNextFile, FindClose if you can't.

Answer (score 2):

For best performance, you're probably going to want to use Win32 APIs like [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=VS.85%29.aspx),  [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [GetFileAttributesEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364946%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and [GetFileSizeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364957%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

If you'd like to avoid Win32 calls, Directory.EnumerateFiles is more efficient than Directory.GetFiles, because it lazily enumerates over the files as they're requested, which may internally use more efficient Win32 APIs. However, since you're going over the network, you may actually want to call Directory.GetFiles to grab them all at once. Experiment.